# Cannot boot ubuntu after installing windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, dualboot

---

## Solved:

In the BIOS settings, there was an option to "enable EFI file as safe" or something. It was greyed out so I set a BIOS admin password to unlock it. I then clicked it, selected HD0 -> grubx.efi. After confirming it brings you back to the option screen. I then disabled secure boot (I swear I disabled this before...), moved the *new grub EFI option* to the top of the boot order and voila!

## How I should have installed Windows for dual boot

[this answer (personally haven't tried it)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu/1120062#1120062) or if you want to partition your drives using ubuntu for some reason like I did...

1. (Assuming you are starting on Linux) get two flash drives. Put your windows image on one [[windows tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/easily-create-windows-10-bootable-usb-ubuntu)] and ubuntu on the other [[ubuntu tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview)]
2. Restart and launch into your Live USB Linux
3. Partition drive using *gparted* into your desired size. Change **master boot record** [MBR] to **GUID Partition Table** [GPT] using *gdisk* if your drive is not GPT already
4. Restart and launch windows installer. Complete the install
5. Restart. If your computer just launches into windows, you will need to use [boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/a/182863) to fix grub

---

My boot-repair pastebin [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4hmZ23V28T/)

## Tried:

1) Everything [here](https://windowsreport.com/fix-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu/#2):

- Repair from Windows – Command Prompt `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`
- Disable Fast Boot
- Use Boot Repair tool
- Windows 10 and Ubuntu are installed in different mode `Partition/boot/efi box checked`

2) Disabled secure boot

## Installing procedure:

1. Start with Ubuntu 19.10 on 1TB SSD and an empty 4GB USB drive
2. Downloaded an Ubuntu 19.10 image and put on USB drive using startup disk creator

   - Also downloaded a Windows 10 image. Would later put on USB drive using woeusb
3. Restart and launch into Live USB Linux
4. Partition using gparted. `sda1` linux, `sda2` NTFS and empty. Use gdisk to convert drive from MBR -> GPT
5. Restart into Ubuntu. Swap linux image for windows on USB
6. Restart and launch into windows installer. Complete install

--- Now I cannot access Ubuntu. If I boot with `UEFI` I get windows, if `Legacy` I get a black screen ---

7. Re-download linux image. Swap windows image for linux on USB using rufus
8. Restart into Live USB Linux. Run boot-repair according to 1) above

## Notes:

- I used `Legacy` instead of `UEFI` to boot into Ubuntu before all this. UEFI would not boot
- Password managers are a life saver. One user/password to access any account when working on fresh installs so much
- Acer aspire R7-371T

[Here is a snapshot of my current drive partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40bAn.png)

## To try:

- Found [this seemingly complete solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from) while writing this
- This requires a full re-install of my ubuntu partition but I will install [ubuntu in uefi mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: You will need to install the grub bootloader to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows.